# При закрытии командной строки в windows 10 перезагружается компьютер

Tags: ruby, консоль, windows-10

При закрытии командной строки (кнопка крестика в углу) в windows 10 перезагружается компьютер.

Также происходит если нажать ctrl+c. Командная строка нормально закрывается от команды exit.

На руби не хотят устанавливаться гемы сасс и компасс (строка вещает об успешной установке, однако нужных материалов в папке установки не появляется, появляется только папка .gem)

пожалуйста, подскажите в чем проблема

Comment: я знаю только один случай, когда от закрывания окна командной строки (cmd.exe) будет перезагружатся комп - это если комп загружен в защищенном режиме с поддержкой командной строки.

Comment: именно так и происходит. без отключения защищенного режима проблему не решить?

Comment: Для установки и настройки руби защищенный режим не нужен. Делайте все это в обычном режиме.

Comment: в какой папке смотрите сасс и компасс? ставили ли с помощью бундлера?

Comment: установил в папку пользователя. добавил несолько плагинов к сублайму, в итоге проблем с компиляцией сасс не имею